# An Issue with Toggled Street View Map to display the map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanna use toggled street View map with a regular google map. Initially, I show the street View. If the user wants to go back to the map, he clicks the toggle button to do that. Basically, it is the opposite of this (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays) 
Becasue, i want to show first street view and when the toggle button is clicked, it goes back to the map.

I have done this code (http://jsbin.com/iwimap/1/edit), but when i click the toggle button, it shows a gray block instead of the google map. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When you click toggle, the `pano` div is covering up your `map-canvas` div.

So to fix, just put that `pano` div inside the `map-canvas` div.

```
<div style="width:500px; float:left; height:500px" id="map-canvas">
    <div id="pano" style="position:absolute;  width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

And to make it display the street view first, just call `toggleStreetView` at the end of `initialize`.

Here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/edowek/1/edit).